# Formatting characters on serial output!

Tags: embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I'm interfacing an SD card to ATmega128 using EFSL.
Card gets initialised, but I get an error saying "Unknown error 0xff(see sandisk docs p5-13)"... on serial port output.

That's not all, I hv used 'sprintf' to form strings which I display on serial port. The puzzling thing is, I'm also getting the actual formatting characters like "%02d" on the output ! I think my application itself is crashing. I can give my source code, but it's too big. If anyone wants to look at it , i'll copy paste it here.

I've also checked the sandisk docs p5-13 but I can't figure it out...

I'm gonna need help on this one guys...
Please let me know if anyone knows anything about this
Thanxs...

Comment: I think you should split this up into two questions.  One for the sprintf and one for the SD card issue.  In both, please post relevant code snippets and links to relevant documentation (board schematics, "sandisk docs", etc).

Comment: I was going to put the code here but it's too big. The .hex file generated is just above 28kB.
But, you are right about 'sprintf', I seriously think this is a problem with 'sprintf'...
Got any ideas as to why sprintf would do that ? Has anyone else had this problem ???

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have written some code for an ATmega8 and written my own printf function that outputs to the serial port [here](http://code.google.com/p/asuro-syd/source/browse/lib/syd/syd_util.c).

the SerWrite function is your function that transfers a 0-terminated unsigned char array to the serial port.

```
#define SIZE_STATUS 80

void ser_printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    uchar STATUS[SIZE_STATUS];
    va_start(args, fmt);
    uchar s = (uchar) vsnprintf(STATUS, SIZE_STATUS, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    SerWrite(STATUS, s); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how, but problem was solved when I used a different card. I tried two 1/2 GB cards with FAT32 formatting; both didn't work, But the card that worked was 16 MB canon card with FAT12 formatting.I'm trying to figure this out. I'll post the answer if I find it,
Thanks anyway guys...